# How to handle a line break in SQL and Python to appropriately return all lines?

Tags: python, sql-server, line-breaks

A string with a line break, e.g. `first line here[linebreak]NEXT ONE` is entered in a GUI-tool and read into an SQL server database where it appears to be a one line string, i.e. `first line here NEXT ONE`. However, if this field is read by Python, it is returned as `NEXT ONEne here`. It seems that the line break is registered somehow, but the handling is wrong as both lines are written on the same line. How to handle the line break in this chain GUI-SQL-Python to appropriately return both lines?

Comment: Have you got a concrete example? See here for how to create a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I'd like to add an example. However, it's difficult to post an useful example here which demonstrates the interaction between Python and an SQL database. I assumed that my problem is so elementary, that experienced user can handle it without an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you use MySQL you can use the escape_string method of mysqldb: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html

This will escape the new line character (e.g. `\n`) before storing it into your database.

Consider using a debugger (e.g.[pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)  or [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb)) to examin the string you store into and the one you receive from the database.

Comment: I'm working SQL server, not with MySQL. How to proceed if the process of storing can not be changed? Is there a chance to identify new line characters in an existing database entry while importing it into Pyhton?

Comment: @BrianSteiner as I wrote in my answer: use a debugger

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the hint. I've now found a workaround-solution: read the the data as ``REPLACE(parameter,char(13),'$')`` with '$' as place-holder. By this, it becomes ``first line here$NEXT ONE``.