# Write CSV data containing \n line breaks

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have JSON data that has strings that may contain "\n" linebreaks:

```
{
    "Id": 12345,
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Normalname"
},
{
    "Id": 76890,
    "firstname": "Paul",
    "lastname": "Evil\nLinebreak" # here's the \n
},
```

I'm trying to write this to a CSV file using Python 3. This is my approach:

```
def write_csv_file(filename, resp):

    # open file
    csvFile = open(filename, "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    # write data
    for line in resp:
       csvWriter.writerow(line.values())

    # close file
    csvFile.close()
```

Now my problem is that the \n character messes up my CSV file by adding an unexpected line break.

So instead of

```
"76890","Paul","Evil\nLinebreak"
```

I get

```
"76890","Paul","Evil
Linebreak"
```

What's the best way to solve this, ideally without changing the data, i.e., maintaining the \n character, but without breaking the CSV structure.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to write `'\n'` instead of line break?

Comment: Yes @olvin-roght - I'll clarify the question.

Comment: No @marcin-orlowski - I'm already wrapping my data in "", as your post suggests.

Comment: This is not "messed up" - this is valid quoted stringcontent inlcuding a newline - any program that is able to read quoted csv will understand it.

Comment: @patrick-artner well at least the Python library mysql-connector-python fails when I try to LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @Sebastian, have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47713903/10824407) question?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I'll take that back, you were absolutely right. Was a different error I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape backslash before putting it into csv.

Change this line

```
csvWriter.writerow(line.values())
```

into this

```
csvWriter.writerow([  s.replace('\n', '\\n') if isinstance(s, str) else s  for s in line.values()])
```

OR to escape all use

```
csvWriter.writerow([ s.encode('unicode_escape').decode() if isinstance(s, str) else s  for s in line.values()])
```

Comment: Do not reinvent a wheel, you can use [`unicode-escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) codec: `s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()`